# Glassfish workaround to work with OpenAM

Tags: glassfish, openam

The IT dept. in the company where I work uses OpenAM to manage web access over the intranet (SSO solution).

As I'm using Glassfish 4.1, which is a container not supported by OpenAM, is there some workaround that I could use OpenAM, without replacing Glassfish? If so, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using OpenAM 13.5.0 for example, it is possible to deploy OpenAM to Payara 4.1.2.172 for example with a bit of a compromise.

**DISCLAIMER**: the following steps allows one to deploy OpenAM to GlassFish/Payara, but this does not mean that this kind of deployment is actually supported by anyone.

So the steps are:

- in the WAR file within the WEB-INF/lib/openam-radius-server-13.5.0.jar you'll need to remove the META-INF/INDEX.LIST file
- you'll need to edit the WEB-INF/web.xml file and remove both the `ws` and `federationrest` servlets and their mappings
- to deploy the WAR you'll need to execute this command:

  ```
  bin/asadmin deploy --name openam --contextroot /openam --property implicitCdiEnabled=false OpenAM-13.5.0.war
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that OpenAM cannot be deployed on Payara (Glassfish). Please refer to the [blog](http://blog.payara.fish/forgerock-integration-with-payara-server-part-1-installation) and the last comment of [this issue](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-9892).

So you may have to use another container, for example, Tomcat.

Comment: I believe the reason for this is due to OpenAM packaging a lot of conflicting libraries, so there's a good chance that some of the classloader isolation features in Payara (introduced after that blog was written) would help to make it deploy. AFAIK this hasn't actually been tested yet.

Comment: I may not replace my container. I need some workaround to use it along with Glassfish. What if I put an Apache Server in front of Glassfish? Is it possible? OpenAM supports Apache Server?

Comment: No. OpenAM does not support Apache Server. Do you want to deploy OpenAM on Glassfish, or want to protect an application on Glassfish by OpenAM?